# How can I create an Eq for an object with an optional property?

Tags: fp-ts

I am trying to create an `Eq` for an object with an optional property.  So far I have tried the following:

```
type Thing = { a: string; b?: string };

const eqThing = Eq.struct<Thing>({
  a: S.Eq,
  b: S.Eq // Type 'Eq<string>' is not assignable to type 'Eq<string | undefined>'.
});

eqThing.equals({ a: "a", b: "b" }, { a: "a" }); // false
```

I think that there must be a way to specify that `b` is `Eq<string | undefined>` but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `Eq.eqStrict`.

```
type Thing = { a: string; b?: string };

const partialStruct = Eq.struct<Thing>({
  a: S.Eq,
  b: Eq.eqStrict
});

expect(partialStruct.equals({ a: "a", b: "b" }, { a: "a" })).toBe(false);
expect(partialStruct.equals({ a: "a", b: "b" }, { a: "a", b: "b" })).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this situation as well. My solution was to create a helper function:

```js
export const getOptionalEq = <A>(eqElement: Eq<A>): Eq<A | undefined> =>
  fromEquals((x, y) =>
    x === undefined || y === undefined ? x === y : eqElement.equals(x, y)
  );
```

Which you can use in the following way:

```js
type Thing = { a: string; b?: string };

const eqThing = Eq.struct<Thing>({
  a: S.Eq,
  b: getOptionalEq(S.Eq)
});
```